# What did this prophecy from the Karaethon Cycle mean in A Memory of Light? (Spoilers)

Tags: the-wheel-of-time, a-memory-of-light

**Warning: heavy spoilers under spoiler text.**

How did this prophecy from the [Karaethon Cycle](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/Karaethon_Cycle) play out in *[A Memory of Light](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Memory_of_Light)*:

> Twice dawns the day when his blood is shed. 
> Once for mourning, once
>   for birth. 
> Red on black, the Dragon's blood stains the rock of Shayol
>   Ghul. 
> In the Pit of Doom shall his blood free men from the Shadow.
>    <sub>*The Great Hunt* Chapter 26: *Discord*</sub>

The US cover of the book has:

[image: A Memory of Light cover]

Showing an Eclipse which I assume fulfils the "Twice dawns the day.." stanza

However, during the Last Battle,

> there is heavy cloud cover and a time dilation effect occurring outwards from Shayol Ghul.

Was this event even visible across the land and did people know what it meant?

> Did it occur (from everyone elses perspective) the day Rand and his followers went into Shayol Ghul, or the day they came out?

I can't recall any reference to the eclipse in the text (I'm sure there was, I must have just missed it and can't seem to drop on it).

Does "Once for mourning, once for birth" refer to

> Rand's "death" and new life in Moridin's body, or something else I missed.

The last two lines of the prophecy seem relatively clear.

Answer (score 6):

Partial answer,

There is mention of an eclipse.

> Aviendha felt a chill and found herself trembling as the light slipped
>   away. Darkness, true darkness, fell. Soldiers across the field looked
>   up in awe, and even fear. The light went out. The end of the world had
>   come. Channeling came suddenly from the other end of the wide valley.
>   Aviendha spun, shaking off her awe. The ground nearby was littered
>   with torn garments, dropped weapons and corpses. All of the fighting
>   was at the mouth of the valley, distant from her, where the Aiel were
>   trying to push the Shadowspawn back into the pass. Though Aviendha
>   couldn’t see much through the darkness, she could tell soldiers were
>   staring at the sky. Even the Trollocs looked awestruck. But then the
>   solid blackness began to move in the sky, revealing first the edge of
>   the sun, and then the sun itself. Light! The end was not upon them.

From Egwene's POV

> She frowned, looking up. What was that shadow? High above, the sun
>   shone in a turbulent sky. Some storm clouds, in patches, some deep
>   black, others brilliant white. It wasn’t a cloud that had suddenly
>   obscured the sun, however, but something solid and black sliding into
>   place.

I seem to remember one from Lan's POV also which I cannot seem to find.

Comment: Do you know which chapters those occurred in?

Comment: There's also mention of it when Elayne gives her speech.

Comment: @NikolaiDante Should be Chapter 23.